# Zend skeleton application Class 'Album\Model\AlbumTable' not found

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my first tutorial using Zend Skeleton App. I'm using Zend Studio 10 + ZendServer and Zf2.2; managed to get the skeleton app working and now got stuck on a missing class problem (see error below). I have tried various approaches but the result is the same: **it's not working**. Here are my files, any help would be appreciated.

My error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Album\Model\AlbumTable' not found in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zf2album\module\Album\Module.php on line 55

Album/Module.php

> namespace Album;
>
> use Album\Model\Album;
>
> use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
>
> use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
>
> use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
>
> class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface {
>
> ```
> public function getAutoloaderConfig()
> {
>     return array(
>         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
>             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
>         ),
>         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
>             'namespaces' => array(
>       // if we're in a namespace deeper than one level we need to fix the \ in the path
>                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
>             ),
>         ),
>     );
> }
>
> public function getConfig()
> {
>     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
> }
>
>
>
> // Add this method:
> public function getServiceConfig()
> {
>   return array(
>           'factories' => array(
>                   'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
>                       $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
>
>                       $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
>                       return $table;
>                   },
>                   'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
>                       $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
>                       $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
>                       $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
>                       return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
>                   },
>           ),
>   );
> }
>  }
> ```

the AlbumController.php

> namespace Album\Controller;
>
> use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController; use
>   Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
>
> class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {  protected
>   $albumTable;
>
> ```
> public function indexAction()
> {
>   return new ViewModel(array(
>           'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
>   ));
> }
>
> public function addAction()
> {
> }
>
> public function editAction()
> {
> }
>
> public function deleteAction()
> {
> }
>
> public function fooAction()
> {
>     // This shows the :controller and :action parameters in default route
>     // are working when you browse to /album/album/foo
>     return array();
> }
>
> public function getAlbumTable()
> {
>   if (!$this->albumTable) {
>       $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
>       $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
>   }
>   return $this->albumTable;
> } }
> ```

AlbumModel.php

> namespace Album\Model;
>
> use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
>
> class AlbumTable {
>       protected $tableGateway;
>
> ```
> public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
> {
>     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
> }
>
> public function fetchAll()
> {
>     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
>     return $resultSet;
> }
>
> public function getAlbum($id)
> {
>     $id  = (int) $id;
>     $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
>     $row = $rowset->current();
>     if (!$row) {
>         throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
>     }
>     return $row;
> }
>
> public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
> {
>     $data = array(
>         'artist' => $album->artist,
>         'title'  => $album->title,
>     );
>
>     $id = (int)$album->id;
>     if ($id == 0) {
>         $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
>     } else {
>         if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
>             $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
>         } else {
>             throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public function deleteAlbum($id)
> {
>     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this isn't a typo in your question, the filename for the class `AlbumTable` should be `AlbumTable.php`, not `AlbumModel.php`.

Comment: That was silly, not to name the file after the class (misread the tutorial); I lost a lot of time trying to figure this out; thank you.